# Servlet is not working

Tags: java, html

Hey for some reason my sql statement will not work, im trying to delete a product by its id but it just wont happen, any suggestion? the *id* is an integer and i think its not working because my input type is text and i have it stored as String *n*.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Admin extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String n = request.getParameter("productid");


        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact","nbuser", "nbuser");
            String query = "delete from product where id = " + n +"";
            PreparedStatement stmt;
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, n);

            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");

            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ey) {
            System.out.println(ey);
        }
        out.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the field is a text type, it needs surrounding quotes - that's why that didnt work. Calling `setString` didnt have any effect as there's no placeholder to accept the id value.

Solution: Add a `PreparedStatement` placeholder:

```
String query = "delete from product where id = ?";
```

This approach protects against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks whereas String concatenation does not.

Comment: THANK YOU! i feel like such a idiot now ive been trying to fix it for an hour

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact","nbuser", "nbuser");
            String query = "delete from product where id = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt;
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(n));

            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");

            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp");
            }
        }
```

make above 2 changes.

Comment: You can also ommit the line `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");` The explicit class loading of the driver is not necessary anymore since JDBC 4

Answer (score 0):

**Found two issues in your code:**

1. You didn't properly set the parameters in the PreparedStatement call.
2. You didn't close the statement and connection.

Try this:

```
    public class Admin extends HttpServlet {


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String n = request.getParameter("productid");


    try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact","nbuser", "nbuser");
            String query = "delete from product where id = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt;
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setString(1, n);

            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if (i > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");

            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp");
            }
        }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ey) {
            System.out.println(ey);
        }

    finally{

         stmt.close();
         con.close();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            Connection con =              DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact","nbuser", "nbuser");
            String query = "delete from product where id = " + n +"";
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();


            int i = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            if (i > 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("index.html");

            }else{
                response.sendRedirect("Admin.jsp");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ey) {
            System.out.println(ey);
        }
```

please try this code,it should works fine

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is  that product id is Integer type in database but u have set it as String
in your code *stmt.setString(1, n);* it should be changed to stmt.setInt(1, n) and query format should be like this *String query = "delete from product where id = ?";*.here is the code for deleting product from database using productId.

```
String query = "delete from product where id = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt;
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setString(1, n);
```

just replace this code it will work...